# PHP-CLI Permission Question

Tags: php, linux, permissions, command-line-interface, sudo

Dear Stackoverflow'er:

I am currently trying to run my script over PHP-CLI. I want to create a file over:
fopen($filename, "w+")

If I run this over this over the webbrowser, the script will be able to create the file, since the folder is owned by 'www-data'.

But if I try to run it over CLI it doesn't work, since PHP has not the same user, so I added www-data into /etc/sudoers with NOPASSWD.
I tried then to run:
sudo -u www-data php ./content.php

But it still doesn't work, do you have maybe a suggestion?

Best,
djcrackhome

Comment: `chmod 777 /path/to/dir`

Comment: It is: 
drwxrwxrwx 3 www-data www-data 4096 2011-06-09 03:35 configs
Which is 777

Comment: I found out how, it is since CLI and APACHE are using different 'php.ini' files, I missed to change the value of PHP safe_mode in the CLI file off, since I did that, everything worked out so far fine, thanks though!

Comment: @Sebastian: Please add your solution as an answer below. After two days you can accept it as "the answer". This will help to keep track which questions have been answered. And yes, you can answer your own questions ;)